# how to find maximum if i have more than one answer

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table:

```
ID CLUSTERID
1     56
1     24
1     24
1      35
2      13
2      24
```

Now, i want to get the following:
I want to count per id, which cluster id repeats most of the time.
For example, in ID=1, CLUSTERID=24 repeats most of the time
In ID=2 i have 2 CLUSTER IDs that repeats the same.
So in the output i will have:

```
ID CLUSTERID
1   24
2   13
2  24
```

The answer that i wrote (and works)
TT is my original table that have 2 columns: ID and CLUSTER ID

SELECT t3.ID,t3.ClusterID,t3.ListingAmount
FROM
(SELECT ID, ClusterID, COUNT(*) AS ListingAmount

 FROM tt

GROUP BY ID, ClusterID) AS t3 LEFT JOIN

 (SELECT ID, MAX(ListingAmount) AS amount

FROM

(SELECT ID, ClusterID, COUNT(*) AS ListingAmount
 FROM tt
GROUP BY ID, ClusterID) AS t2
GROUP BY ID) AS BB ON BB.id=t3.id
WHERE  BB.amount=t3.ListingAmount

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: I was just about to post a solution, but it would not work with the limited SQL MySQL has....

Comment: There were here 2 solutions that dont work. Someone deleted them?

Comment: So no thoughts of how to implement it in MySQL? :) I didnt know that there is such a big difference between MySQL and SQL

Comment: MySQL lacks all of the modern SQL features other DBMS have. In this case window functions would make the job quite easy. Btw. `SQL` is only a query *language*. It is **not** a DBMS product.

Answer (score 0):

Can't think of a more elegant solution right now (I'm sure there is), but it seems to do the job:

```
select t1.id, 
       t1.clusterid,
       t1.cnt
from (
    select id, 
           clusterid, 
           count(*) as cnt
    from foo
    group by id, clusterid
) t1 
  join (select id, 
                max(cnt) as max_count
        from (       
            select id, 
                   clusterid, 
                   count(*) as cnt
            from foo
            group by id, clusterid
        ) tm
        group by id
  ) t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
      and t1.cnt = t2.max_count
order by t1.id, t1.cnt;
```

SQLFiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2cacc/3